# Jquery Mobile 1.4 Beta 1 Back Button text

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I'm trying to override the back button text for all back buttons in my jquery mobile 1.4 Beta 1 app.

My header snipit

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-beta.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

init.JS

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
    $.extend($.mobile, {
        loadingMessage: "My new loading label..."
    });
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Volver";
});
```

When I check  $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText is is set correctly as documented here http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-beta.1/dist/demos/toolbar/ but the back button  still says "Back".

Not sure if I'm setting it to late as this guy http://blog.moldoveanu.net/2010/11/jquery-mobile-translating-the-back-and-loading-labels/ shows doing it this way on an old version or is this possibly a 1.4 beta bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### jQuery Mobile 1.4 Beta

As per the changes in **Alpha**, `data-add-back-btn` is added to **toolbar** not **page** div. So you need to override `$.mobile.toolbar` options, not `$.mobile.page`.

Unlike previous versions, `data-add-back-btn` is added to page div.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rd5Mm/)**

```js
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
  $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Volver";
});
```

**Reference: [Change - Alpha 1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/09/24/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-4-beta/)**

Comment: @Jeff you're welcome. You can report issues here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile